# How can I plot routes "from" a position "to" another position on Google Maps v2?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

How can I plot routes "from"  a position "to" another position on Google Maps v2?

I did a simple aplication with the api v2, but now I would plot routes to different position in the map.

is it possible? thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use -
  final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="+from +"&daddr="+to));

intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

startActivity(intent);

Comment: Thank you is just that I need, but if I would plot the route through bus or walk? Is possible add some parameter?